# How to make conditional regex

Tags: regex

I want to create regex where the {{if gender == }} will be fixed and "Male", "Female", "Both" and "Unknown" will be dynamic values to be checked. I have tried something like this

```
/^\{\{if gender == "Male"|"Female"|"Both"|"Unknown"\}\}$/i
```

but this only checks {{if gender == "Male" and it's not good.
Also, I have tried something like this

```
/^\{\{if gender == ("Male"|"Female"|"Both"|"Unknown")\}\}$
```

but this only shows me a group.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just make it a non-capturing group i.e. `"(?:Male|Female|Both|Unknown)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put parenthesis on the first part too and it works:

```
^(?:\{\{if gender ==) (?:"Male"|"Female"|"Both"|"Unknown")\}\}$
```

I am using ?: to make it Non-capturing group. Alternately, it can be used as follows:

```
^(\{\{if gender ==) ("Male"|"Female"|"Both"|"Unknown")\}\}$
```

[Regex working link](https://regex101.com/r/6wOEjn/1)